# Why the new thread also exits after closing of Swing GUI in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Here is the code of my program. Problem is that whenever i close the main GUI
My new thread also exits. Which by definition should not because it is not a daemon thread. I am working in eclipse and any help would be appreciated.

```
public class HomeScreen extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HomeScreen frame = new HomeScreen();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while(true){
                                System.out.println("Hello");//This should print "Hello" forever but this thread exits after i close main GUI
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's still printing merrily on my PC, how did you close the window? Cmd+Q? Alt+F4?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I just closed my Swing GUI

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hmm.. this is one of the few times I've used the 'cannot be reproduced' (yes, same behavior here) close reason. Oddly it also mentions posting an MCVE (which the OP effectively did).

Comment: @AndrewThompson That one is a bit of a "catch all", I'd like to see "low quality"/"unlikely to help future readers" be moved to a separate option, but that's me :P

Comment: Unable to reproduce here too in Eclipse 4.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_65 (64-bit). What versions are you running?

Comment: @Andreas I am using Eclipse 4.5.0 on Java 1.8.0_65 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all. I got the trick just added a statement to run thread infinitely

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: That would suggest that at some point the frame was set to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` which wasn't in you example code

Comment: *"You are absolutely correct.."* In future, please include as much in the [mcve] as it takes to cleanly compile it (e.g. the imports, and closing `}`) and then copy/paste it to a new project or class definition to **test the behavior still remains.** The code you posted was almost an MCVE, but failed on that last, vital, point. And to @LaxmikantRevdikar, good use of your ESP & excellent to see you're using it for good rather than evil. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanx for pointing out those important things , i will definitely keep these in mind for future. StackOverFlow restrict me to accept my own answer for two days.

Comment: @LaxmikantRevdikar *"i will definitely keep these in mind for future"* You won't need to wait long into the future till you can accept the answer. Please don't forget to do so. :)

Comment: Oops! I didn't realize you'd answered your own question. :P At ease - smoke 'em if you got 'em.